# Create new arrays based on a NSArray which contains dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array of dictionaries which results from an Core Data fetch request with results type of `NSDictionary`:

```
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"endCalYear",@"endMonth",@"periodLength"];
```

A sample result `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` looks as follows:

```
{
    endCalYear = 2007;
    endMonth = 12;
    periodLength = 12;
},
{
    endCalYear = 2006;
    endMonth = 9;
    periodLength = 3;
},
{
    endCalYear = 2006;
    endMonth = 6;
    periodLength = 3;
},
{
    endCalYear = 2006;
    endMonth = 3;
    periodLength = 3;
}
```

What would be the most efficient way to create (three) separate arrays **endCalYear** = 2006, 2007, 2008; **endMonth** = 3, 9, 12 and **periodLength** = 3, 6, 12 from the NSArray given?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `valueForKey`:

```
NSArray *endCalYearArray = [resultArray valueForKey:@"endCalYear"];
```

Comment: Thank you, Martin! Would it be possible to access a specific index-based value without first creating an NSArray, for instance returning the 2nd item in "endCalYear", which would result in 2007 (i.e. combining `valueForKey`and an index?

Comment: @AlexR: `[[resultArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"endCalYear"]`